# URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName Errors (Java)

Tags: java

I am currently writing a function to upload files into server.
My filename format is typical like this ACTION#USERNAME.TXT, I run into the error

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=41; regionStart=38; regionLength=-28

when on this line of code

```
writer.append("Content-Type: " + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName)).append(LINE_FEED);
```

I did some debugging and realised the problem was caused by the character '#'. Taking it out allows the file to be uploaded. The actual file allows for the # character so I don't really understand why would # cause a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Could anyone enlighten me please?

Comment: Works for me: https://ideone.com/sEXYso Can you provide a complete stacktrace?

Comment: @RC. It does not work. It's supposed to return `text/plain`, or rather, that is what OP is expecting. If you change the `#` to `%23`, that is what you'll get.

Comment: @Andreas yeah [mcve] for the win

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#` sign has special meaning in a URL.

The `#fragment` part of a URL (see [syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax)) is never sent from the client to the server. It is a part of the URL that is handled by the client. It can be sent from the server to the client in links and redirects.

To include a `#` sign (or any other special character) in the file name, it must be escaped/encoded using `%NN` hex codes.

The encoding of `#` is `%23`, but you really should use a URL encoder.

Comment: Thanks for the simple and concise answer. URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8"); did the trick. Thanks!